# wedge product of standard represention

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

For symmetric group $S_{n}$, we have standard representation $V$. We can prove that wedge product $\wedge^{p}V$ is irreducible representation of $S^{n}$ for any $p$. Since we have one-to-one correspondence between irreducible representations of $S_{n}$ and Specht modules $S^{\lambda}$. I was wondering how can we prove that $S^{n-p,1^{p}}\cong \wedge^{p}V$.
I can check that dimensions of these two spaces are the same. But I have a hard time to find a proper map between these two spaces.

Comment: Are you looking for an explicit map between the spaces, or just a proof that they are isomorphic (e.g. have the same character)? If it's the first, what is your definition of a Specht module?

Comment: @Joppy Just have to prove they are isomorphic. I think it's not easy to compute all the characters for each element in $S_{n}$.